# Table is not created in WAMP

Tags: plugins, table

I don't know where the mistake is. My code is not creating a table in WAMP:

```
function subscribe_table() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'_databasesubs';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    if ( $wpdb->get_var( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE '. $table_name ) != $table_name ) {  
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                sno int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, email varchar(25), name varchar(25), contact int(10)
            ) $charset_collate;";
    }

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'subscribe_table' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try edit Privileges for your wordpress database user from phpMyAdmin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ramamoorthy,

I reviewed your comment and there is no issue in code but check following details.

Please deactive and again active your plugin. If you still encounter issue then follow the further steps from: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-database-tables-for-plugins/

PS: If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much AddWeb Solutions :) :) It works now. :)